cannot import name 'path_to_string' from 'keras.utils.io_utils' (C:\Users\Hello\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py)
Please note the below error tracing following initiating an import statement:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File d:\udemy-python\accelerometer_python\cnnmodeltraining1\cnnmodeltraining1\mainapp.py:17
    from keras.models import Sequential

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:21
    from keras import models

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py:18
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py:34
    from keras.engine import training as training_lib

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:43
    from keras.saving import pickle_utils

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py:24
    from keras.saving import save as save_module

  File ~\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py:26
    from keras.utils.io_utils import path_to_string

ImportError: cannot import name 'path_to_string' from 'keras.utils.io_utils' (C:\Users\Hello\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py)


what does the code look like for that error statement?

When I install keras (version 3.3.3), there is no such file ...\keras\saving\save.py. I suggest updating your Keras version, that would likely fix the issue.
